# How to access oracle database's source from Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How to access oracle database's source from Postgresql database

We want to access oracle database source from postgresql database server

My oracle database(11g) in one server and postgresql(9.3.5) in another server

Thanks

Ragav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Foreign Data Wrapper for Oracle (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#oracle_fdw) and query the relevant Oracle views - user_source, dba_source...?

Comment: Hi Jayadevan
i went through oracle_fdw.Actually it was not there in postgresql datbase's bin folder.
I downloaded oracle_fdw file separately and i placed all files in coresponding folders
in our postgresql database
like oracle_fdw.dll file in bin folder
and oracle_fdw.control,oracle_fdw--1.1 in share/extension folder

after that i executed 
CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw;

but it is giving error

ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/oracle_fdw.dll": The specified module could not be found.
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: You should keep the dll file in C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/, that is what the error message says. I am afraid I don't have experience working with Windows systems. If you installed using the GUI installer, there may be an option to install extensions using that?